# Why is the plural form used in describing the creation of man?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, theology, creation

When man is being created, it is Betzelemenu Kidimutenu, why is this in plural form? Is this implying that the oneness of God Echad is somehow contradicted?

Comment: I added some tags and I edited your title to make it more descriptive.

Comment: I think this has been answered elsewhere on this site.

Comment: Voted to close as a dup of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31906/who-is-us-in-genesis-126-if-god-is-one